# write_only_fields doesnt have any effect in django rest framework serializer

Tags: django-rest-framework

While **read_only_fields** works  flawlessly for me. Write only fields are still showing up in GET request even after doing this ->

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    class Meta:
        write_only_fields = ('current_password','new_password')
```

It used to work till some time back in the same codebase, but seems to have broken now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has been removed as announced in the [3.2 release notes](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.2-announcement/#deprecations)

You now need to use `extra_kwargs` instead.